# What is the first mockumentary style show?

Tags: comedy, cinema-history, documentary, parody

There are a lot of great mockumentary style comedy shows such as *[The Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Office)*, *[Parks and Recreation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parks_and_Recreation)*, *[Modern Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Family)*, etc. My question is who invented this style? Who was the first to make a show or a movie that way?

Comment: The concept of fake documentaries has been around [since the 1930s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_Without_Bread).

Comment: @JakeGould - "[A Hard Day's Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Hard_Day%27s_Night_(film))" is a good early example of a fully comedic fake documentary

Comment: @JakeGould No not only TV shows. Just edited the question. I want to know how it started whether it is a movie or a show

Answer (score 6):

> There are a lot of great mockumentary style comedy shows such as *The
>   Office*, *Parks and Recreation*, *Modern Family*, etc. My question is who
>   invented this style? Who was the first to make a show or a movie that
>   way?

#### Early examples of mockumentaries.

The general genre of what you describe is known as a [“mockumenary”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockumentary). An early example of this genre is the 1933 film by Luis Buñuel titled, [*Las Hurdes: Tierra Sin Pan (Land Without Bread)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_Without_Bread)

> The movie is a documentary, parodying the exaggerated documentaries of
>   travelers across the Sahara being filmed at the same time. One of
>   Buñuel's points is that there are plenty of terrible subjects for a
>   documentary right in Spain.

But besides that film, [Orson Welles’ 1938 radio adaptation of H. G. Wells’ *The War of the Worlds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Worlds_(radio_drama)) is considered another early mockumentary:

> The first two thirds of the one-hour broadcast was presented as a
>   series of simulated news bulletins, which suggested an actual alien
>   invasion by Martians was currently in progress.

#### Mockumentaries in popular TV and film.

The [1964 Beatles film *A Hard Day's Night*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Hard_Day%27s_Night_(film)) is a mockumentary that supposedly follows the Beatles as they deal with fame and stardom but is clearly done in a very exaggerated style and was a big in-joke that was serious/fake and very meta on many levels. For example:

> When Ringo is asked if he’s a mod or a rocker, he replies “Uh, no, I’m
>   a mocker.”

The list is fairly deep but as far as TV goes there was [*The Rutles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rutles) who were a parody band formed by some Monty Python members that mocked *The Beatles* and appeared on the 1975/76 comedy British comedy series [*Rutland Weekend Television*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutland_Weekend_Television). In 1978 a *Rutles* television film titled [*All You Need is Cash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Need_Is_Cash) was released.

And in 1979 comedian/film-maker Albert Brooks released his first film [*Real Life*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Life_(1979_film)) which is a parody of the 1970s PBS series [*An American Family*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_American_Family) which is arguably the first [reality television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reality_television) show ever made:

> The first feature directed by Albert Brooks, who also co-authored the
>   screenplay, it is a spoof of the 1973 reality television program *An
>   American Family* and portrays a documentary filmmaker named Albert
>   Brooks who attempts to live with and film a dysfunctional family for
>   one full year.

Later on an episode of the 1983 British comedy series, [*The Comic Strip Presents…*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Comic_Strip) focused on a fake heavy metal band named *Bad News* and followed this fake band on tour. This preceded the release of the 1984 American film [*This is Spinal Tap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_Spinal_Tap) which many people consider one of the most successful modern mockumentaries that inspired many others. But again, that was a film and not a TV show.

#### Modern TV mockumentary lineage.

The 1995 British radio mockumentary, [*People Like Us*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_Like_Us_(mockumentary)) featured a bumbling interviewer who—in each episode—would follow and profile the lives of normal everyday people; aka: literally people like us. The radio show was made into a TV series in 1999 as well which was followed 2 years later by the British version of [*The Office*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Office_(UK_TV_series)).

So—in my humble opinion—the general concept of a mockumentary has existed for years in various forms/media. But as far as television shows specifically go we have to thank the British for creating [*The Rutles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rutles) in 1975 which then inspired others—such as [*People Like Us*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_Like_Us_(mockumentary))—and lead to [*The Office*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Office_(UK_TV_series)) in 2001 which then lead to [*Parks and Recreation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parks_and_Recreation) and [*Modern Family*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Family) in 2009.

Comment: [People Like Us](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0214362/) deserves an honourable mention, & actually beat the Office by a couple of years… I'll never forget the policeman who was getting another station to fax over some blank paper because their machine was running out.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for finding the wikipedia link… which led me to this interesting revelation… "A third series was planned but was cancelled in favour of The Office."